# Understanding nounと考える

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-で

From [this article](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010858331000/k10010858331000.html):

> 静岡県の伊豆は、キンメダイという魚や温泉などが有名な観光地です。
>   Shizuoka's Izu is famous for hot springs and *some weird* fish
>   伊豆の海岸を走っている伊豆急行**で**、赤いキンメダイをイメージした電車の運転が始まることになりました。
>   A train service, that looks like a red fish, will start running along the Izu coast, *run by* Izu Express.
>   たくさんの人に観光に来てもらうために、**伊豆急行と**近くの６つの市と町が**考えました**。
>   For the purpose of getting lots of people to come sight seeing, 6 nearby towns and cities **thought up the Izu express**

The part in bold in the last sentence is just a guess. I assume that と is quotative here? I'm guessing that it was something like:

> [Izu express would be a great idea]と考える

but with "would be a great idea" omitted as being too obvious to everyone but me. Is my thinking correct?

I also have a question on the second sentence. Does 伊豆の海岸を走っている modify 伊豆急行? It feels to me like it should modify 電車の運転 but I worry that the comma prevents that from being possible. Finally, is で 'by means of' here or copula. I think it must by "by means of". If it was copula then we'd have "**It** is the Izu express which runs along the Izu coast and ..." but we don't yet know what '**it**' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't see the と as quotative.
2. The `伊豆の海岸を走っている` does modify `伊豆急行`. I wouldn't worry about the comma as those are suggestive rather than part of the rule like in Engish.

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot. I was reading it as though the towns had invented the 伊豆急行 rather than that the towns **and** 伊豆急行 had invented this particular service. Any thoughts on which で this is?

Comment: oh sorry about that, forgot to answer. で would be the "pronoun" usage or "by means of" in this case. Not the copula (which I assume means です。im not too familiar with those terms :P)